# If I send an email to my own server, does it pass through ISP?

Tags: networking, email, postfix, smtp, imap

This may be a super newbie question, I have an email server running Postfix/Dovecat with SMTP for send and IMAP for receiving.

I have two accounts--a@myserver.com and b@myserver.com. I want to send emails to b@myserver.com from a@myserver.com, basically sending and receiving within the same server. I am curious what exactly goes on when I send an email to the same server.

Question: Does it go through ISP or does everything happen all locally without ISP knowing? I want to be able to send without passing through ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails to local mailboxes *SHOULD NOT* go via your ISP with proper configuration
**BUT** number of sub-optimal and botched configurations is incredible e.g. some admins want internal mails to undergo anty-virus scans provided by their ISP disregarding privacy concerns.

Send email to yourself from the host and inspect `Received:` headers in the received message to check delivery path.

Comment: it is anti-virus